# Why are my python variables acting globally during recursion?

Tags: python, variables, recursion

I have a recursive function that doesn't work the way I want it to. Inside the function, I have a variable called sum. I want the variable to be local / a different one for each function call, so that the final sum becomes the sum of all earlier function calls. However, it seems like the variable is acting globally, so every time the function is called, the sum variable is set to 0, and that is what is returned in the end. I have the same problem with the list: for each function call, an element is removed from my_list in all the different recursion frames, rather than just the local frame as I want it to. Is this how variables are supposed to work during recursion in python? If it is, how can I change the code to make it work the way I want it to?

By the way, the purpose of the function is to find out if there exists a subset of a list that adds up to the number n, but this is not very relevant for understanding the issue I have.

I have searched for similar posts, and I found someone arguing that you're not invoking a recursion unless you use the return statement to return the function like this:

return f(n - x, remove(list, x))

However, if that is the case, I don't see how I can both return the function and add the value to the sum at the same time.

```
list1 = [3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4]

# removes an element from the list, and returns the result
def remove(list_, x):
    list_.remove(x)
    return list_

# recursive function
# should return 1 or more if there exists a combination of numbers in the list
# that add up to the number n
def f(n, my_list):
    sum = 0

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if len(my_list) == 0:
        return 0
    for x in my_list:
        sum += f(n - x, remove(my_list, x))

    return sum


print(f(15, list1))
```

There exists a subset of the list that adds up to 15: for example (5, 1, 5, 4), so the output should be at least 1, but because of the fact that the variables are acting globally, the output is always 0.

Comment: whats up with the `for x in list` ? Dont use reserved words.

Comment: same for the keyword `sum`. Those are all reserved functions. If they are hard to know whether they are depending on where you write the code, use an IDE like VSCode or Pycharm. I also like using ipython for scripting.

Comment: True, forgot to add the _ in the end like I did with list_ in the remove function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one list object being created, so when elements are removed, the are removed everywhere. You need to copy the list before passing it down. Try this:

```py
list1 = [3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4]

# removes an element from the list, and returns the result
def remove(list_, x):
    list_.remove(x)
    return list_

# recursive function
# should return 1 or more if there exists a combination of numbers in the list
# that add up to the number n
def f(n, my_list):
    sum = 0

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if len(my_list) == 0:
        return 0
    for x in my_list:
        sum += f(n - x, remove(list(my_list), x))

    return sum


print(f(15, list1))
```

Comment: Thank you! Works exacly the way it's supposed to now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4]

# removes an element from the list, and returns the result
def remove(list_, x):
    del list_[x]
    return list_

# recursive function
# should return 1 or more if there exists a combination of numbers in the list
# that add up to the number n
def f(n, my_list, total):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if len(my_list) == 0:
        return total
    else:
        total += my_list[0]

    return f(n - 1, remove(my_list, 0), total)



print(f(15, list1, 0))
```

Your code is not working with recursive algorythm, I updated code as recursive.

Answer (score 0):

`sum` is an `int`; this is immutable -- you get a local variable on each entry to the routine.

However, `my_list` is a mutable parameter to the function; all calls share the same object.  Instead of passing the list, pass a copy of the truncated list.  You can do this more easily with slicing.  Try something like the solutions already available on line for this problem: at each recursion step, advance in one branch including the lead element; advance in the other without it

```
def f(n, my_list):
    if n == 0:
        return True
    if len(my_list) == 0:
        return False
    if f(n, my_list[1:]):
        return True
    if f(n - my_list[0], my_list[1:])
        return True

    return False
```